# integrate atmosphere.js in react-native application

Tags: reactjs, react-native, atmosphere.js

I want to integrate atmosphere.js in react native application . I know atmosphere.js will work without any browser browser involve .

Answer (score 1):

expect josp I could port atmospher.js to react-native specific. Just replaced the dependencies with corresponding node packages.

Comment: Hi, can you share me the github, I'm learning atmosphere + react native now. Thank you!